# How to configure Pyramid + uWSGI + SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, pyramid, uwsgi

I am developing a web app using Python **3.5**, Pyramid **1.7**, uWSGI **2.0.11** and SQLAlchemy **1.0.9**. I have heard that when using uWSGI with multiple workers we should use a uWSGI postfork function to connect to the SQLAlchemy database. Otherwise SQLAlchemy will share the connection pool between the different forks causing issues:

- [Preforking](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#preforking-vs-lazy-apps-vs-lazy)
- [SQL alchemy with multiple workers](http://lists.unbit.it/pipermail/uwsgi/2011-May/002079.html)
- [Integrating uWSGI & Cassandra avoiding Forking issues](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/python/2.5/cqlengine/third_party.html#uwsgi)

Following this advice I have added this code in my pyramid application on file `my_app/__ini__.py`, for creating the connection engine after the postfork event:

```
def main(global_config, **settings):

    try:
        from uwsgidecorators import postfork
    except ImportError:
        # We're not in a uWSGI context, no need to hook dbs connection
        # to the postfork event.
        engine = engine_from_config(settings, prefix='sqlalchemy.')

    else:
        @postfork
        def init():
            """ Initialize dbs connexions in the context.
                Ensures that a new connexion is returned for every new request.
            """
            global engine
            engine = engine_from_config(settings, prefix='sqlalchemy.')


    # Retrieves database connection
    def get_db(request):
        global engine
        connection = engine.connect()
        def disconnect(request):
            connection.close()
        request.add_finished_callback(disconnect)
        return connection

    config = Configurator(settings=settings, root_factory=my_factory)
    config.add_request_method(get_db, 'db', reify=True)
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

Could someone with previous experience confirm if this is the correct approach using preforking in uWSGI? I am a bit confuse, as I don't really understand if the connection to certain pool is defined during the engine creation or  when calling `engine.connect()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I have heard that when using uWSGI with multiple workers we should use a uWSGI postfork function to connect to the SQLAlchemy database. Otherwise SQLAlchemy will share the connection pool between the different forks causing issues." **[citation needed]** :)

In my experience, stock-standard SQLAlchemy setup has no issues with either UWSGI's multi-process or multi-thread model and the app does not need to be aware of UWSGI at all.

SQLAlchemy's Session object, when configured with [scoped_session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html), is a thread-local, so while it may appear that you're sharing a global variable between threads, the variable actually represents an individual connection/transaction in each thread.

If you use UWSGI preforking instead of thereads you can use the `scopefunc` parameter of [scoped_session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session) to make it return a different connection per worker - I would imagine you can use `uwsgi.worker_id()` as the hashing key.

I also don't quite understand what you're trying to achieve with `def get_db()`, but it looks highly suspicious - it looks like you're opening and closing a new connection to the database on every request, which is ewww... :) I suggest you to have a look at one of [stock Pyramid scaffolds](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/tutorials/wiki2/basiclayout.html#application-configuration-with-init-py) which illustrate how to configure SQLAlchemy with Pyramid. The magic words are "ZopeTransactionExtension" and "scoped_session" as illustrated [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/tutorials/wiki2/basiclayout.html#content-models-with-models-py)

Comment: Hi @Sergey, thanks for the reply :) uWSGI by default uses [Preforking](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#preforking-vs-lazy-apps-vs-lazy), which basically is loading the app just once and sharing the result with the other workers, that's why you may get issues sharing connections with SQLAlchemy or Cassandra. (Just added references). That's why people usually configure uWSGI with the  **lazy-apps** option to avoid such behavior. As far as I know using SQL alchemy ORM like you proposed is way slower than a core implementation :)

Comment: @Ander: I've added a paragraph on specifying custom scopes to the answer, which should solve your issue with preforking. I never suggested to use the ORM (which actually is not _that_ slow), I suggested to use a properly-configured Session, which is an abstraction for connection/transaction, with connections checked out from a pool instead of re-connecting on every request. If you think your home-grown bicycle-reinventing approach is going to be faster than using a Session then you're in for a surprise :)

Comment: mmh.. correct me if I am wrong but I believe sessions can only be used in ORM SQLAlchemy (they are imported from **sqlalchemy.orm**)  and there is no session in the SQLAlchemy core docs. My app is just too big at the moment to be moved from Core to an ORM implementation. My home-grown approach is just something I used in my previous [aiopyramid project](http://aiopyramid.readthedocs.io/) to avoid having async issues with SQLAlchemy. I don't believe is the best but it has worked surprisingly well so far :)

Comment: There's a `Session.execute` method which "Executes a SQL expression construct or string statement within the current transaction" - http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.execute - this method works similarly to `Connection.execute()`

Comment: That will simplify a lot moving to transactions, thanks mate.

Comment: You need to call `engine.dispose` after the fork.

Answer (score 2):

You *must* do one, and only one, thing after forking -- call the `dispose()` method on the engine.

As per sqlalchemy's docs:  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#engine-disposal

> When a program uses multiprocessing or fork(), and an Engine object is copied to the child process, Engine.dispose() should be called so that the engine creates brand new database connections local to that fork. Database connections generally do not travel across process boundaries.

from memory, my code looks something like this:

```
engine = engine_from_config(settings, prefix='sqlalchemy.')

try:
    import uwsgi

    def postfork():
        engine.dispose()
    uwsgi.post_fork_hook = postfork

except ImportError:
    pass
```

The `scoped_session` stuff deals with closing/releasing connections within the pool -- without the `dispose`, you run the risk of multiple workers managing the same db connection independently.

tldr; fork-safe and thread-safe are different concepts in python. (see also http://www.dctrwatson.com/2010/09/python-thread-safe-does-not-mean-fork-safe/).